# Error when execute hdfs zkfc command

Tags: javascript, hadoop, hdfs, apache-zookeeper

I am trying to run hdfs using 3 namenode machines, 2 datanodes machine and 1 client machine.

When I execute `hdfs zkfc –formatZK` 
I have the next fatal error, I don't know  why, because I have try the cluster other times and it works, but now it does not work.

```
16/01/21 15:05:14 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Session: 0x25264b6c3d90000 closed
16/01/21 15:05:14 WARN ha.ActiveStandbyElector: Ignoring stale result from old client with sessionId 0x25264b6c3d90000
16/01/21 15:05:14 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: EventThread shut down
16/01/21 15:05:14 FATAL tools.DFSZKFailoverController: Got a fatal error, exiting now
org.apache.hadoop.HadoopIllegalArgumentException: Bad argument: –formatZK
    at org.apache.hadoop.ha.ZKFailoverController.badArg(ZKFailoverController.java:251)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ha.ZKFailoverController.doRun(ZKFailoverController.java:214)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ha.ZKFailoverController.access$000(ZKFailoverController.java:61)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ha.ZKFailoverController$1.run(ZKFailoverController.java:172)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ha.ZKFailoverController$1.run(ZKFailoverController.java:168)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.SecurityUtil.doAsLoginUserOrFatal(SecurityUtil.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ha.ZKFailoverController.run(ZKFailoverController.java:168)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.tools.DFSZKFailoverController.main(DFSZKFailoverController.java:181)
```

I can run without any error the next commands:

```
namenode1$ `hadoop-daemon.sh start journalnode`
namenode2$ `hadoop-daemon.sh start journalnode`
namenode3$ `hadoop-daemon.sh start journalnode`

namenode1$ `hadoop namenode -format`
namenode1$ `hadoop-daemon.sh start namenode`

namenode2$ `hadoop namenode -bootstrapStandby`
namenode2$ `hadoop-daemon.sh start namenode`

namenode1$ `hadoop-daemon.sh start zkfc`
namenode2$ `hadoop-daemon.sh start zkfc`
namenode3$ `hadoop-daemon.sh start zkfc`
```

But when I go the the web page using namenode1:50070 it appears like standby and the namenode2:50070 to.
I try using `hdfs haadmin -getServiceState nn01` with nn01 and nn02, but both appears like standby.

My configurations are the next:

etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
172.16.8.191 name1
172.16.8.192 name2
172.16.8.193 name3
172.16.8.202 data1
172.16.8.203 data2
172.16.8.204 client1
```

zoo.cfg

```
tickTime=2000

        dataDir=/opt/ZooData

        clientPort=2181

        initLimit=5
        syncLimit=2
        server.1=172.16.8.191:2888:3888
        server.2=172.16.8.192:2888:3888
        server.3=172.16.8.193:2888:3888
```

core-site.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>

<configuration>
 <property>
    <name>fs.default.name</name>
    <value>hdfs://auto-ha</value>
 </property>
</configuration>
```

hdfs-site.xml

```
<configuration>
     <property>
        <name>dfs.replication</name>
        <value>2</value>
    </property>
     <property>
        <name>dfs.name.dir</name>
        <value>file:///hdfs/name</value>
    </property>
     <property>
        <name>dfs.data.dir</name>
        <value>file:///hdfs/data</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.permissions</name>
        <value>false</value>
    </property>
     <property>
        <name>dfs.nameservices</name>
        <value>auto-ha</value>
     </property>
     <property>
        <name>dfs.ha.namenodes.auto-ha</name>
        <value>nn01,nn02</value>
     </property>
     <property>
        <name>dfs.namenode.rpc-address.auto-ha.nn01</name>
        <value>name1:8020</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.namenode.http-address.auto-ha.nn01</name>
        <value>name1:50070</value>
     </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.namenode.rpc-address.auto-ha.nn02</name>
        <value>name2:8020</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.namenode.http-address.auto-ha.nn02</name>
        <value>name2:50070</value>
     </property>
     <property>
        <name>dfs.namenode.shared.edits.dir</name>
        <value>qjournal://name1:8485;name2:8485;name3:8485/auto-ha</value>
     </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.journalnode.edits.dir</name>
        <value>/hdfs/journalnode</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.ha.fencing.methods</name>
        <value>sshfence</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.ha.fencing.ssh.private-key-files</name>
        <value>/home/vagrant/.ssh/id_rsa</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.ha.automatic-failover.enabled.auto-ha</name>
        <value>true</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>ha.zookeeper.quorum</name>
        <value>name1:2181,name2:2181,name3:2181</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

Comment: <property> <name>dfs.ha.automatic-failover.enabled</name> <value>true</value> </property> is this property enabled?

Comment: Hello, I have this property in the hdfs-site.xml, what do you want to say which if this property is enabled? thanks @ravindra

Comment: It should be enabled in namenode. Have a look at step by step process at https://googleweblight.com/?lite_url=https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.0/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HDFSHighAvailabilityWithQJM.html&ei=P3rdOloY&lc=en-IN&s=1&m=506&ts=1448893230&sig=ALL1Aj4CGuPEaaCCyBWltwK64x03FsIV1A

Comment: I don't understand the problem, I just have this configurations, and my problem is when I try to execute "hdfs zkfc -formatZK" my zookepers start sucesfully, so I don't know. I am 20, and I am very new to hdfs. @ravindra

Comment: Do you have two namenodes or three namenodes? You can delete your other question unless it is different... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34024215/error-executing-hdfs-zkfc-command

Comment: Hi, @cricket_007 I have trying two different configurations, because my configuration with two namenodes and thats configurations failed, so now I am trying with other tutorial and three namenodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I copied the command "hdfs zkfc –formatZK" from microsoft-word, the line is longer than the real line of the command you have to put in the terminal.

```
Word command: hdfs zkfc –formatZK

Real command: hdfs zkfc -formatZK
```

Answer (score 0):

On zoo.cfg your zookeeper clientPort=2181

And on hdfs-site you had given port as 3000 (try changing to 2181)

i.e

```
  <property>
       <name>ha.zookeeper.quorum</name>
        <value>172.16.8.191:3000,172.16.8.192:3000</value>
  </property>
```

Comment: sorry @Rajendra I don't have updated configurations, now it is updated.