# Error executing hdfs zkfc command

Tags: apache, hadoop, hdfs, apache-zookeeper, high-availability

I am new to hadoop, hdfs.. I have do the next steps:

I have started zookeeper in the three namenodes:

```
*vagrant@172:~$ zkServer.sh start
```

I can see the status:

```
*vagrant@172:~$ zkServer.sh status
```

Result Status:

```
JMX enabled by default
    Using config: /opt/zookeeper-3.4.6/bin/../conf/zoo.cfg
    Mode: follower
```

with jps command only appear jps and sometimes appear quaroom too:

```
*vagrant@172:~$ jps
    2237 Jps
```

When I run the next command.

```
* vagrant@172:~$ hdfs zkfc -formatZK

16/01/07 16:10:09 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server 172.16.8.192/172.16.8.192:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
16/01/07 16:10:10 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Socket connection established to 172.16.8.192/172.16.8.192:2181, initiating session
16/01/07 16:10:11 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session establishment complete on server 172.16.8.192/172.16.8.192:2181, sessionid = 0x2521cd93c970022, negotiated timeout = 6000
Usage: java zkfc [ -formatZK [-force] [-nonInteractive] ]

16/01/07 16:10:11 INFO ha.ActiveStandbyElector: Session connected.
16/01/07 16:10:11 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Session: 0x2521cd93c970022 closed
16/01/07 16:10:11 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: EventThread shut down
16/01/07 16:10:12 FATAL tools.DFSZKFailoverController: Got a fatal error, exiting now
org.apache.hadoop.HadoopIllegalArgumentException: Bad argument: –formatZK
    at org.apache.hadoop.ha.ZKFailoverController.badArg(ZKFailoverController.java:251)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ha.ZKFailoverController.doRun(ZKFailoverController.java:214)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ha.ZKFailoverController.access$000(ZKFailoverController.java:61)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ha.ZKFailoverController$1.run(ZKFailoverController.java:172)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ha.ZKFailoverController$1.run(ZKFailoverController.java:168)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.SecurityUtil.doAsLoginUserOrFatal(SecurityUtil.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ha.ZKFailoverController.run(ZKFailoverController.java:168)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.tools.DFSZKFailoverController.main(DFSZKFailoverController.java:181)
```

Any help for this error would be a great help for me.

My configuration are the next:

## bashrc

```
###JAVA CONFIGURATION###
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin

###HADOOP CONFIGURATION###
HADOOP_PREFIX=/opt/hadoop-2.7.1/
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_PREFIX/bin:$HADOOP_PREFIX/sbin

###ZOOKEPER###
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/zookeeper-3.4.6/bin
```

## hdfs-site.xml

```
<configuration>
 <property>
  <name>dfs.replication</name>
  <value>2</value>
 </property>
 <property>
  <name>dfs.name.dir</name>
  <value>file:///hdfs/name</value>
 </property>
 <property>
  <name>dfs.data.dir</name>
  <value>file:///hdfs/data</value>
 </property>
 <property>
  <name>dfs.permissions</name>
  <value>false</value>
 </property>
 <property>
  <name>dfs.nameservices</name>
  <value>auto-ha</value>
 </property>
 <property>
  <name>dfs.ha.namenodes.auto-ha</name>
  <value>nn01,nn02</value>
 </property>
 <property>
  <name>dfs.namenode.rpc-address.auto-ha.nn01</name>
  <value>172.16.8.191:8020</value>
 </property>
 <property>
  <name>dfs.namenode.http-address.auto-ha.nn01</name>
  <value>172.16.8.191:50070</value>
 </property>
 <property>
  <name>dfs.namenode.rpc-address.auto-ha.nn02</name>
  <value>172.16.8.192:8020</value>
 </property>
 <property>
  <name>dfs.namenode.http-address.auto-ha.nn02</name>
  <value>172.16.8.192:50070</value>
 </property>
 <property>
  <name>dfs.namenode.shared.edits.dir</name>
  <value>qjournal://172.16.8.191:8485;172.16.8.192:8485;172.16.8.193:8485/auto-ha</value>
 </property>
 <property>
  <name>dfs.journalnode.edits.dir</name>
  <value>/hdfs/journalnode</value>
 </property>
 <property>
  <name>dfs.ha.fencing.methods</name>
  <value>sshfence</value>
 </property>
 <property>
  <name>dfs.ha.fencing.ssh.private-key-files</name>
  <value>/home/vagrant/.ssh/id_rsa</value>
 </property>
 <property>
  <name>dfs.ha.automatic-failover.enabled.auto-ha</name>
  <value>true</value>
 </property>
 <property>
   <name>ha.zookeeper.quorum</name>
   <value>172.16.8.191:2181,172.16.8.192:2181,172.16.8.193:2181</value>
 </property>
</configuration>
```

## core-site.xml

```
 <configuration>
<property>
  <name>fs.default.name</name>
  <value>hdfs://auto-ha</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

## zoo.cfg

```
 tickTime=2000

        dataDir=/opt/ZooData

        clientPort=2181

        initLimit=5
        syncLimit=2
        server.1=172.16.8.191:2888:3888
        server.2=172.16.8.192:2888:3888
        server.3=172.16.8.193:2888:3888
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In file hdfs-site.xml:

*I have change all the IPs for the name of the machine.
Example:
172.16.8.191 --> machine_Name1

Then in file etc/hosts:

*I have add all the IPs with their respective names

And now it is working perfectly.